# passing html entities as function parameters

Tags: php, html-entities

```
<?php
$var1 = str_replace('\n', "<br/>", $var1);
$var2 = str_replace('\n', "<br/>", $var2);
$var3 = str_replace('\n', "<br/>", $var3);

/*
$var1 = nl2br($var1);
$var2 = nl2br($var2);
$var3 = nl2br($var3);
*/
?>

<a href="javascript:" class="history_link" style="color:<?php echo $color; ?>" onclick="showPopUpWindow(
   '<?php echo htmlentities($var1, ENT_QUOTES); ?>',
   '<?php echo htmlentities($var2, ENT_QUOTES); ?>',
   '<?php echo htmlentities($var3, ENT_QUOTES); ?>'
   );">
```

My situation is this: I have some text from a DB and I need to pass it to a JS function as parameter using the onclick event of a  tag (I know this sucks and everything, but I'm working over the code of a random freelancer guy from 4 years ago and I have no other choice). I don't know what the text contains. It may have special chars ($, #, %, ", ' etc.), it may contain HTML tags. I tried using htmlentities, nl2br, replacing nl with br (str_replace), changing the quotes of the onclick event to single and double but it doesnt work.
There are 3 parameters I have to pass.

Here's a part of my code. ANY help would be appreciated.

Comment: Put the final result of the `<a>` tag here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `json_encode`?

```
<a href="javascript:" class="history_link" style="color:<?php echo $color; ?>" onclick="showPopUpWindow(
   <?php echo json_encode($var1); ?>,
   <?php echo json_encode($var2); ?>,
   <?php echo json_encode($var3); ?>
   );">
```